# How to show map key and value of a struct inside a json

Tags: json, go

I've this piece of code.

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

func divisionsHandler(c *gin.Context) {
    divisions := getDivisionRows()
    json := make(map[int]string)
    for divisions.Next() {
        var d Division
        err := divisions.Scan(&d.id, &d.name)
        json[d.id] = d.name
        if err != nil {
            panic(err.Error())
        }
    }
    c.JSON(200, json)
}
```

The result is

```
{
    1: "games",
    2: "technology",
    3: "tekk",
    4: "home entertainment",
    5: "toys & stationery"
}
```

I am trying to convert that json in something like

```
{
    [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "games"
    },
    ...
    ]
}
```

but how?

Comment: That is not valid json. An object can't contain just an array. Without the opening and closing curly brackets it makes more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want a json array instead of a json object?

Instead of loading a `map[int]string`, why not simply make a `[]Division`?

```
list := []Division{}
for divisions.Next() {
    var d Division
    err := divisions.Scan(&d.id, &d.name)
    list = append(list, d)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
}
```

You'll need to change the field names to `ID` and `Name` so that the json package can serialize them, but you should end up with somthing more like:

```
[
  {"ID":1,"Name":"Games},
  ...
]
```